# how to get Jquery data to php correctly?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, sql

Hello i have a form like this:

```
<tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input data-check="f_n" type="text" name="first_name" /></td>
<td data-msg="f_n"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input data-check="l_n" type="text" name="last_name" /></td>
<td data-msg="l_n"></td></tr>
```

now i did a jquery `$.post` to connect to php to desplay a error in case is needed, so far i have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-check]').click(function(){
        var a = $(this).data('check');
        $.post('website/register/checks.php',, function(data){
            $('[data-msg='+ a +']').html(data);
        });
    });
 });
 </script>
```

I'm really confuse, on how to send the correct data according to the users input.. and show it in the correct `<td></td>`

Comment: `.php',,` must be a typo.

Comment: Is your table wrapped in a `<form>`?

Comment: sorry, i know something must go inside there to show what data im working with in the php file, but i dont know what goes there

Comment: yes it is wrap in a `<form>`

Comment: @Blender seems not, OP seems want to pass data from input to php

Comment: between those comma's is where your string goes. As to put results into the td elements, within the post callback function you would append data as needed. You are on the right track :)

Comment: try this $('[data-msg="'+ a +'"]').html(data); note the double quotes arround variable a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the post data as the second parameter of `$.post`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-check]').click(function(){
        var a = $(this).data('check'), post_data = {};
        post_data[a] = $(this).val();
        $.post('website/register/checks.php', post_data, function(data){
            $('[data-msg='+ a +']').html(data);
        });
    });
 });
```

Comment: doing this how would i change the `+ a +` to show the error message in there?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-check]').click(function(){
    var a = $(this).data('check');
    $.post('website/register/checks.php',{data:a}, function(data){ //<--typo here ', ,'
        $('[data-msg="'+ a +'"]').html(data);
    });
  });
});
```